# async await with promises is then block required

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

How to basically async await properly? I have created a helper for AsyncStorage which async awaits automatically but do the users of this also have to use `async await` or promise approach to get the value?

This code works but unable to use the syntax correctly.

here is my code:

```
class AsyncStorageHelper {
  static getItem = async (key: string) => {
    let value: any = "";
    try {
      value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error item: ${value}`);
      throw new Error(`Error ${value}`);
    }
    return value;
  };
}

AsyncStorageHelper.getItem("logins")
  .then(result => {
    if (result) {
      if (result === "1") {
        navigate(SCREEN1);
      } else {
        navigate(SCREEN2);
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    navigate(LOGINSCREEN);
  });
```

How can I convert the `AsyncStorageHelper` code to async await as depending on the result I want to navigate to different places.

Comment: async functions return promises, so yes, the caller of the function has to treat the return value like a promise. (Is that your question?)

Answer (score 2):

await must be used inside a async function.

```js
async function helper() {
  try {
    const result = await AsyncStorageHelper.getItem("logins");

    if (result) {
      if (result === "1") {
        navigate(SCREEN1);
      } else {
        navigate(SCREEN2);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    navigate(LOGINSCREEN);
  }
}

helper()
```

Answer (score 1):

Async functions and promise-returning function can be used externally in the same manner.

```
AsyncStorageHelper.getItem("logins")
  .then(result => {
    if (result) {
      if (result === "1") {
        navigate(SCREEN1);
      } else {
        navigate(SCREEN2);
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    navigate(LOGINSCREEN);
  });
```

Is the same as:

```
// note: this code must run in another async function
// so we can use the keyword await
try {
  const result = await AsyncStorageHelper.getItem("logins");
  if (result) {
    if (result === "1") {
      navigate(SCREEN1);
    } else {
      navigate(SCREEN2);
    }
  }
} catch (err) {
  navigate(LOGINSCREEN);
}
```

Note: your code has an unknown code path. What happens when `AsyncStorageHelper.getItem("logins")` returns a falsy value? You essentially have a noop and this might not be the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AsyncStorageHelper {

  static async getItem(key : string) {
    let value: any = ""
    try {
      value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error item: ${value}`)
      throw new Error(`Error ${value}`)
    }
    return value
  }
}

try {
  const result = await AsyncStorageHelper.getItem("logins")

  if (result)
    (result === "1") ? navigate(SCREEN1): navigate(SCREEN2)

} catch(err) {
  navigate(LOGINSCREEN)
}
```